# Validate text field input array

Tags: php

I have 2 text fields and if you press a plus button it generates another 2 with jQuery.

for each set only one of the fields has to have a value ie: this would pass validation:

```
email        number 
email
             number
```

but if both fields were left empty then validation should fail.

I am not sure how to achieve this. My current validation requires both fields to not be empty.

```
    foreach($this->contact_email as $email) {
        if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $this->errors[] = 'Invalid email address';
        }
    }



    foreach($this->contact_number as $number) {
        if(strlen($number) < 10) {
            $this->errors[] = 'Contact number should be 10 characters long';
        }
    }
```

HTML:

```
   <?php foreach($contactDetails as $details): ?>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col">
                   <br>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Contact Email address" name="contact_email[]" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($details->contact_email); ?>">
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                   <br>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Contact phone number" name="contact_number[]" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($details->contact_number); ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Loop over one of them, and use the current loop index/key to access the associated field in the other, then check if both of those are empty.

Comment: @04FS, not really sure how to access the other field if I only loop over one of them. I thought maybe something like this would be a place to start but it only gives me key and value of the email field. `foreach($this->contact_email as $key => $val) {`
           
        }`

Comment: Now you got the key, so you can access the corresponding field in the other array using `$this->contact_number[$key]`

Comment: @04FS, I tried this but even if I fill out one field I still get a validation error where validation should pass. `foreach($this->contact_email as $key => $val) {
            if(empty($val && empty($this->contact_number[$key]))) {
                $this->errors[] = 'At least one field required';
            }
        }`

Comment: `empty($val && $this->contact_number[$key])` is nonsense, check both fields on their own.

Comment: @04FS, okay, got it working. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can always be sure to have the same count of email and number fields, you can solve it with a single loop like this:

```
foreach($this->contact_email as $index=>$email) {
    $number = $this->contact_number[$index];
    $validMail = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    $validNumber = strlen($number) < 10;

    if ($validMail || $validNumber) {
        continue;
    }

    if(!$validMail) {
        $this->errors[] = 'Invalid email address';
    }

    if(!$validNumber) {
        $this->errors[] = 'Contact number should be 10 characters long';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code. If I leave both fields blank validation does not fire and it inserts a blank row. It should require that at least one of the 2 fields on each row has some input

Comment: that sounds like you're not checking for the length of `$this->errors` before creating the database entries, because as far as I see it should work with the code I provided. If either of the two fields is not blank, it doesn't add a new string to the errors array.

Comment: Okay, I modified this a bit and got it working, thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

I suppose they are inside a `<form>` so what you can do inside your controller si to do something like that :

```
if(!empty($_POST['email'])){
//your code here
};
```

Hope I have understood you're questio and I help you.